# Invalid index exception when using BulkExecutor in CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, bulkupdate

I have an error when I'm trying to use BulkExecutor to update one of the properties in CosmosDb. The error message is "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

Important point- I don't have partition key defined on my collection.

Here is my code:

```
SetUpdateOperation<string> player1NameUpdateOperation = new SetUpdateOperation<string>("Player1Name", name);
var updateOperations = new List<UpdateOperation>();
updateOperations.Add(player1NameUpdateOperation);
var updateItems = new List<UpdateItem>();
foreach (var match in list)
{
  string id = match.id;
  updateItems.Add(new UpdateItem(id, null, updateOperations));
}
var executor = new Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor.BulkExecutor(_client, _collection);
await executor.InitializeAsync();
var executeResult = await executor.BulkUpdateAsync(updateItems);
var count = executeResult.NumberOfDocumentsUpdated;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you resolved it ?

Comment: No, I was experimenting with this, wasn't critical. Gave up. Probably will check again few months later after few more releases of the library.

Comment: @MaximAlexeyev have you found anything?

Answer (score 1):

If I run the bulk executor on a collection without a partition key, I get the same error. If I run it with a collection that does have it and i specify it, the bulk executor works fine.

Pretty sure they just don't support it right now through the bulk executor api, just use the normal cosmos api for updating the doc as a workaround for now.